# chemfig: Drawing arrow from intermediate back to same starting molecule - u> arrows involved

Tags: arrows, chemfig

I am trying to reproduce a very old article figure.

I want to draw a straight arrow from the intermediate A back to starting molecule A. Do I have to do this with `tikzpicture`s and `arc`s etc? Is there perhaps a very simple way of doing this?

```
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\setchemfig{arrow angle=0,arrow coeff=1,arrow style={}}
\schemestart A + B\arrow{-U>[][w]}[0]\chemfig{C}\arrow{-U>[][x]}[0]D
\arrow{-U>[y][]}[-90]A + E
\arrow{-U>[z][]}[-90]F
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \setchemfig{arrow angle=0, arrow coeff=1, arrow style={}}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{@{a1}A} + B
    \arrow{-U>[][w]}[0]
    \chemfig{C}
    \arrow{-U>[][x]}[0]
    D
    \arrow{-U>[y][]}[-90]
    \chemfig{@{a2}A} + E
    \arrow{-U>[z][]}[-90]
    F
    \schemestop
    \chemmove{\draw[shorten <=4pt,shorten >=4pt] (a2) -- (a1);}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit** (for compounds)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
%\setchemfig{scheme debug=true}
\setchemfig{arrow angle=0, arrow coeff=1, arrow style={}}
\schemestart
\chemfig{H_2O}
\arrow(aa1--pl1){0}[,0]
\+
\arrow(--bb1){0}[,0]
\chemfig{B}
\arrow{-U>[][w]}[0]
\chemfig{C}
\arrow{-U>[][x]}[0]
\chemfig{D}
\arrow(--pl2){-U>[y][]}[-90]
\+
\arrow(--aa2){0}[180,0]
\chemfig{H_2O}
\arrow(@pl2--ee1){0}[,0]
\chemfig{E}
\arrow(@pl2--){-U>[z][]}[-90]
\chemfig{F}
\schemestop
\chemmove{
    \draw[shorten <=4pt,shorten >=4pt] (aa2) -- (aa1);
    \draw[red, shorten <=4pt, shorten >=4pt] (aa2) -- node[midway, above, blue] {or better?} (aa1 |- aa2) -- (aa1);
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry. I simplified the problem too much. When A is a chemfig molecule. i.e. A =\chemfig{H_{2} for example.  The arrow is not displayed or the pdf output is over several pages

Comment: @4gottenMyMaths see edit

Answer (score 2):

A very simple solution

```
\schemestart \chemfig{@bA} + B\arrow{-U>[][w]}[0]\chemfig{C}\arrow{-U>[][x]}[0]D
    \arrow{-U>[y][]}[-90]\chemfig{@aA} + E
    \arrow{-U>[z][]}[-90]F
    \arrow(@a--@b){->}
    \schemestop
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

alter arrow coeff to say 1.1 and rerun. Return value to original and arrow is then displayed.